# Why doesn't the bdo tag have options for vertical text?

Tags: html, internationalization, bidi

Why does the bdo tag only allow the specifying of left to right text, and right to left text? Why doesn't it allow authors to specify vertical text, like what Japanese used to use and Mongolian script uses?